# Why is my ASP.NET Web forms rendering slow?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

I have some complex ASP.NET Web Forms website. Tracing showed this:
[image]

So basically, all my database calls and other complex, time-consuming things often take less time then ASP.NET Web Form render method. How to make it faster?

Rendering often takes around 200-300ms or even more. That is already above Google's reccomendation for time for first byte

Is it because it is not small? But it is around 40kb (size of rendered website).
I if was database query that is slow I would know what to do it? But here I don't know how to make faster, apparanetly, internal ASP.NET Web forms method?

Comment: Well, you  would have to provide a huge boatload of more information here. Trying to blame webforms is sheer folly - it not webforms, but would be the amount of things you have on that page. More stuff = more time to render - kind of simple. You might want to copy the page and start pulling parts out - see which part is taking all the time.

Comment: I can put my render method here. And relax, I am not blaming web forms :D

Comment: It is probbably too much markup to show for SO. I can only suggest that you make a copy, and then start hacking out (removing) parts until you find the one part that is slow. Sometimes it can be some left over. We had a page loading slow - turns out is what a 2 meg in side background image we forgot to replace with a smaller one. So, I would copy the page - and start chopping out parts until it loads fast, and you thus might be able to narrow down what is taking so long.

Comment: Disable ViewState on as much Controls as possible. That should help also.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have codes in the Page_Load event, u might have to look into the codes, not remove it, but look for another way to write them.

Second, check all controls on the form, remove idle controls if any, or look for alternate controls to replace some of the ones you used